# Add JS tag before </body>

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic

I need to place JS tag(`<script src=...`) as last tag before `</body>`.  How to do that at runtime using JS or jQuery?

Comment: If this is the way you are loading an external script, then [`jQuery.getScript()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) is default solution within jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use append function provided by Jquery.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('body').append('<script src="yourfile.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>');
});
```

Comment: the quotes are messy there. use this : '<script src="yourfile.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>'

Answer (score 2):

```
var myscript = $("<script src='...'>...</script>");
$("body").append(myscript);
```

Comment: @Hooch: the OP wants to add it just before `</body>`.

Comment: @Hooch: Why do you say this is _bad_? This is _exactly_ what OP wanted and in some cases it is even best practice.

Answer (score 1):

```
$( "body" ).append(
  "<script src=\"your script source\" type=\"text/javascript\"></script>"
);
```

and if you want to add it as the first element inside body use prepend

```
$( "body" ).prepend(
  "<script src=\"your script source\" type=\"text/javascript\"></script>"
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Jquery .appendTo()](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/) :

> Insert every element in the set of matched elements to the end of the
>   target.

```
$('<script src="/path/to/script.js"></script>').appendTo('body');
```